# How do I bind 2 select options in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, bind, ng-options

```
<select  ng-model="listaAddAct.zone"  ng-options="zona.route for zona in zone">
<option value="">Selected 1</option>
</select>

<select  ng-model="listaAddAct.zone1"  ng-options="zona1.route for zona1 in zone1">
<option value="">Selected 2</option>
</select>
```

What do i need:

When I make a selection in the first select and automatically my code to make a selection in the second option select.

can someone help me :)

Comment: Take a look on this demo, might help u: http://plnkr.co/edit/SBmjs9TAwqBxoOtaDJUx?p=preview

Comment: yeah ... that's it, more or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it :)

```
if($scope.zone){
   $scope.zone.forEach(function(zona){
        if(zona.Ruta == $scope.listaAddAct.ridicari.Nume){
            $scope.listaAddAct.zone = zona;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful for further visitors to mark (your own) answer as accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly. You need to use `ng-change`

```
<select  ng-model="listaAddAct.zone"  ng-options="zona.route for zona in zone" ng-change="listaAddAct.zone1=listaAddAct.zone">
<option value="">Selected 1</option>
</select>
```